# Can I play Dragon Quest X on a US account on a Nintendo Switch and does it have English language?

Tags: nintendo-switch, nintendo-eshop, dragon-quest-x

If i buy the game on a secondary JP account will i be able to play with my normal account, and does it have a english language option? (i'm Not from Japan)